# Calculating $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^{3}}{(3+\frac{1}{n})^{n}}$

Tags: calculus

I need help to calculate this limit:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^{3}}{(3+\frac{1}{n})^{n}}$$

Comment: Is the limit $1$

Answer (score 8):

$$0 \le \frac{n^3}{(3+\frac{1}{n})^n} \le \frac{n^3}{3^n} $$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n^3}{3^n} = 0$$
So $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^3}{(3+\frac{1}{n})^n}  = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

And this is why $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n^3}{3^n} = 0$.
${3^n}=(1+2)^n=1+n2+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}2^2+\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}2^3+\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{4!}2^4+...+2^n>\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{4!}$

And so,

$0 \le \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n^3}{3^n} \le \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n^3}{\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{4!}}= 0$